# Troubleshooting complete disappearance of bluetooth on windows10

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth

Earlier today, I tried to connect wireless headphones to my dell inspiron 7490 only to discover that it couldn't connect. I checked the bluetooth settings and to my surprise discovered that the 'toggle bluetooth' icon had gone. I had read online and found that this is not an uncommon problem.

I have since tried a slew of things, all of which haven't worked and have appeared to make things worse.

1. I tried restarting my laptop, this did not work.
2. I tried running the bluetooth troubleshooter, but this (as typical with windows products) only told me what I already knew- that bluetooth wasn't enabled on my laptop.
3. I went to settings -> update & security -> check for updates. Downloaded and installed the updates, this still didn't work.
4. I then went to device manager, where I had to click on 'view hidden devices', where I saw bluetooth. And tried updating all installed bluetooth drivers. Note here that 'bluetooth generic adapter was not here'.
5. I then uninstalled all bluetooth drivers, such that windows would automatically reinstall them when I ran a next set of updates. I ran the updates and bluetooth is still not present in the device manager menu.

Are there any other steps to mitigate this? I feel like I have tried everything and it hasn't helped. I really don't know what caused the bluetooth toggle to be removed in the first place.

Comment: What model is your Bluetooth adapter and what is its driver?

Comment: If existing device driver has become corrupt, this may also result in the “Missing Generic Bluetooth Driver” error. Please download/install the specific driver visiting the Manufacturer’s official Site. After uninstalling all Bluetooth drivers go to the manufacturer site and download the latest driver as per your system configuration.